YOLOV11 No Labels found in cache
I am trying to train a model that classify tanks. I have 9 labels. I am working on Google Collab:
Here is the folder structure:

Now, I got this tank dataset from Roboflow. The way I initially loaded the dataset in is that I used the download code that was given to me on the website. My initial code looks like this
!mkdir {HOME}/datasets
%cd {HOME}/datasets

from google.colab import userdata
from roboflow import Roboflow

ROBOFLOW_API_KEY = userdata.get('ROBOFLOW_API_KEY')
rf = Roboflow(api_key=ROBOFLOW_API_KEY)

workspace = rf.workspace("liangdianzhong")
project = rf.workspace("capstoneproject").project("russian-military-annotated")
version = project.version(4)
dataset = version.download("yolov11")

The next line of code shows me initializing the train model
%cd {HOME}

!yolo task=detect mode=train model=yolo11s.pt data={dataset.location}/data.yaml epochs=1 batch= 60 imgsz=640 plots=True

And my error is thrown here:
Transferred 493/499 items from pretrained weights
TensorBoard: Start with 'tensorboard --logdir runs/detect/train7', view at http://localhost:6006/
Freezing layer 'model.23.dfl.conv.weight'
AMP: running Automatic Mixed Precision (AMP) checks...
AMP: checks passed ✅
train: Scanning /content/datasets/Russian-military-annotated-4/train/labels... 1026 images, 33 backgrounds, 0 corrupt: 100% 1026/1026 [00:00<00:00, 1995.16it/s]
train: New cache created: /content/datasets/Russian-military-annotated-4/train/labels.cache
albumentations: Blur(p=0.01, blur_limit=(3, 7)), MedianBlur(p=0.01, blur_limit=(3, 7)), ToGray(p=0.01, num_output_channels=3, method='weighted_average'), CLAHE(p=0.01, clip_limit=(1.0, 4.0), tile_grid_size=(8, 8))
val: Scanning /content/datasets/Russian-military-annotated-4/valid/labels... 9 images, 9 backgrounds, 0 corrupt: 100% 9/9 [00:00<00:00, 1585.35it/s]
val: New cache created: /content/datasets/Russian-military-annotated-4/valid/labels.cache
WARNING ⚠️ No labels found in /content/datasets/Russian-military-annotated-4/valid/labels.cache, training may not work correctly. See https://docs.ultralytics.com/datasets for dataset formatting guidance.
Plotting labels to runs/detect/train7/labels.jpg... 
optimizer: 'optimizer=auto' found, ignoring 'lr0=0.01' and 'momentum=0.937' and determining best 'optimizer', 'lr0' and 'momentum' automatically... 
optimizer: AdamW(lr=0.000714, momentum=0.9) with parameter groups 81 weight(decay=0.0), 88 weight(decay=0.00046875), 87 bias(decay=0.0)
TensorBoard: model graph visualization added ✅
Image sizes 640 train, 640 val
Using 2 dataloader workers
Logging results to runs/detect/train7
Starting training for 1 epochs...

      Epoch    GPU_mem   box_loss   cls_loss   dfl_loss  Instances       Size
        1/1      15.2G      1.125      5.288      1.594         18        640: 100% 18/18 [00:22<00:00,  1.24s/it]
                 Class     Images  Instances      Box(P          R      mAP50  mAP50-95): 100% 1/1 [00:00<00:00,  1.50it/s]
                   all          9          0          0          0          0          0
WARNING ⚠️ no labels found in detect set, can not compute metrics without labels

How to resolve this issue?

Have you validated your data? I.e is all the files and images and labels in their correct directory?  Is the yaml pointing to the correct folders? Try moving a training data point to the validation datapoint as the algorithm seems to be able to detect the training data.

Nevermind it was my dataset. the test data didnt have labels
